# Calculate the sum of products using a td attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Sum</th>
        </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="sum">
            <td><input class="qty" type="text" value="1" /></td>
            <td>German format: </td>
            <td data_price="1375.5">1.375,50 &euro;</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sum">
            <td><input class="qty" type="text" value="1" /></td>
            <td>English format:</td>
            <td data_price="1375.5">&euro;1,375.50</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sum">
          <td><input name="text" type="text" class="qty" value="1" /></td>
          <td>French format:</td>
          <td data_price="1375.5">1 375,50 &euro;</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sum">
          <td><input name="text2" type="text" class="qty" value="1" /></td>
          <td>Italian format:</td>
          <td data_price="1375.5">&euro;1,375.50</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sum">
             <td><input class="qty" type="text" value="1" /></td>
             <td>Spanish format:</td>
            <td data_price="1375.5">&euro; 1.375,50</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Total</td>
            <td id="total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I want to use the value of attribute "data_price" to calculate the SUM like in this link : 
http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/77/

I want to use only the attribute "data_price" in calculation and not the .

Please help, I'm still beginner in jquery :)

Comment: Shouldn't those `data` attributes have a dash, not an underscore?

Comment: Please stop writing tags and thanks. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your price cells, you should use this format:

```
<td data-price="1375.5">&euro;1,375.50</td>
```

i.e. with a hyphen, not underscore

You can then use:

```
$('td').data('price')
```

to access its value - see http://api.jquery.com/data

e.g.

```
var sum = 0;
$('.sum').each(function() {
    var q = parseFloat($(this).find('.qty').val());
    var p = parseFloat($(this).find('td').eq(2).data('price'));
    sum += q * p;
});
$('#total').text(sum);
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/gzYhN/

Comment: In fiddle, this is "data-price" and not "data_price"

Comment: @ChristopeCVB I've removed the link altogether and added some sample code here.

Comment: @Bizboss define "doesn't work".  Under Chrome it correctly puts 6877.5 in the 'total' cell.  I didn't put in a 'change' handler to make it auto update, though.  [I have now, though]

Comment: @ChristopheCVB please remove out-of-date comments

Comment: Thanks, but I can't let my initial script : http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/63/ to work with the new modifications (td attribute data_price) can anyone help ? 

Thanks and sorry for my ignorance ! :(

Comment: @Bizboss that's because your new fiddle doesn't look like what you've posted here!  You have no `data-price` (or `data_price`) attributes at all in that fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var sum=0;
$('tbody > tr >  td[data_price]').each(
   function()
   {
      sum += parseFloat(this.attr('data_price'));
   }
);
```

Comment: @ChristopheCVB - there is no infomation about html5 in question

Comment: http://www.google.fr/search?q=html+data+attribute&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @ChristopheCVB - I am talking about he question posted by OP in that no where written its of html5

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ptfKJ/

This example is using your original HTML code.

Comment: when you are changing qty? Just add events handler and perform some checks: http://jsfiddle.net/ptfKJ/2/