# Jquery math sum method

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

I need to sum some money value, i have this html

```
<div class=''>54,44</div>
<div class=''>34,10</div>
<div class=''>44,00</div>
<div class=''>14,50</div>
```

How can i make an alert with the sum of these div text?? ( the right sum!! ;-) ) 
Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the sum of products using a td attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731042/calculate-the-sum-of-products-using-a-td-attribute)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add some class like `money` (or use `$("div")` selector) and do something like this:

```
var sum = 0;
$(".money").each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", "."));
});

alert(sum);
```

Comment: `sum += +$(this).text().replace(",", ".");` is shorter.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, its worthwhile putting a data-attribute on each div with the raw amount, devoid of any locale-specific formatting.

eg/

```
<div data-amount="55.44">54,44</div>
```

Then assuming these div's are identifiable you can simply do

```
var total = 0;
$('some-selector-for-your-divs').each(function(){
   total += parseFloat($(this).data('amount'));
});
```

Edit: Duh! parseInt on monetery amounts fixed.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of using a separate attribute for the non-locale-specific value.

Comment: @Alnitak - me either, voting on SO can be weird sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

A comma isn't a legal decimal separator in Javascript, so you'll have to convert the commas into decimal points:

```
var sum = 0;

$('div').each(function() {
    var v = $(this).text().replace(',', '.');
    sum += parseFloat(v);
});

alert(sum);
```

Comment: You need to add condition !isNaN

Comment: @Fedor only if the input is user supplied

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;
$('div').each(function() {
sum += $(this).text();
});
alert("The sum is "+ sum);
```

Comment: This'll concatenate all the strings together.

Comment: You may want to replace the "," with a "." before add them up.

Comment: exactly jamiec, this should be understood!

Comment: @user - but the OP specifically asked for the sum!

Comment: sorry i was just trying to help and that too quick :) thats i have upvoted ur comment too jamiec so that he gets the right ans

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
   var sum=0;
    $('div').each(function(){
    sum+=parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',','.');
    });
```

Comment: This will work, so long as you replace the commas in the values with decimal points: `sum+=parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',','.');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
$('div').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).text().replace(',', '.'); // Replace , with .
    sum += parseFloat(val);
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/9GVNT/1/))

**Update**
The base 10 thing was crap.

Comment: @Alnitak Leftover from first (unsuccessful) test using `parseInt()` :-S

Answer (score -2):

```
var sum=0;
$('div').each(
    function(){
         sum+=Number($(this).html());
    }         
);
alert(sum  );
```

Don't forget convert numbers to coreect format

Comment: @downvoters, if you explain somthing, maybe I will answer better next time

Comment: 1. not replacing the comma.  2.  using `.html()` instead of `.text()`, 3. Not using the function designed for parsing floats.